# Lot's of swap is in use but ram has plenty of free space

Tags: swap

To fix the issue(system freeze when copy large file) i changed the scheduler from `cfq` to `deadline`. I am not sure that scheduler affect the swap uses or not. I have 8 GB of ram, 2.0 GHz `corei7` processor and 8 GB swap. `swappiness` value is low but Ubuntu still using 10 MB swap space and system stuck when try to switch the windows. I have attached a screenshot of `gnome-system-monitor`. I was downloading 4-5 large files( >=1.5 GB <= 4.0 GB) and watching a 720p movie using gnome-mplayer.

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq 

cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
10

sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda
ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD10JPVX-80JC3T0                    
    Serial Number:      WD-WX11AA3E8770
    Firmware Revision:  01.01A01
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call 10MB "lots".

Comment: @muru vm.swappiness=10, so it's lot in sense that I have 63% ram available.

Comment: Nope. A small duration of high memory usage may cause a process to be swapped out, and if it's not awakened soon enough, it may not be swapped back in, 10 MB is fair. You have only shown us ~20s worth of RAM usage. What about an hour or more?

Comment: You should really be looking into the performance of your disk, IMHO. With so much activity going on, it's going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: You have 8 GiB of swap space total. 10 MiB is a tenth of a percent of that. Definitely not "lots." If you only had 10 MiB of swap, then it would certainly be "lots." You don't state anything about what type of disk you are using though. It sounds to me more like your issue is that copying large files is causing heavy disk I/O, which is causing delays in processing.

Comment: in my opinion using swap is not necessary just delete swap partition. i never use swap. what do you say @muru

Comment: swapping occurs for those programs which are not touched for hours. so linux puts them in swap

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Since I am using ~1.7GB of swap right now on an 8GB RAM/8GB Swap, system,I wouldn't be one to recommend deleting swap. OP: The Disks utility has a benchmark option for disks. It can only do a read-only benchmark while the disk is in use, but if you could boot to a live environment and try a read-write benchmark, that might be informative to you.

Comment: @muru do we really need swap in normal use,other than benchmarking ?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds I fight the same problem often, and I believe it to be a page cache issue rather than a swap issue:  if I cause the cache to be flushed, my system becomes responsive again.